# PostgreSQL timeouts on local server with complex query and fairly large dataset

Tags: sql, postgresql, timeout, datagrip

**Background**

I have a local server of PostgreSQL on my machine that contains a fair amount of data on car and motorcycle insurance that I need to prepare for statistical analysis. I'm running a fairly complicated query involving several joins on 3 different tables, one of which has ~100m rows and the other two of which have ~30k or so rows. All tables have < 15 columns. Note that this query is actually wrapped in a `COPY TO` statement, because I want to output the result to a CSV file for later import and analysis in `R`.

My machine is a 64bit Windows 10 Pro machine with 6 cores and 32gb of RAM. I run my Postgres queries in DataGrip (because I like the GUI better than PGAdmin). I should say at the outset that I'm a RDBMS novice in general. Postgres version is 13.3.

**The Problem**

This big query in question, which is ~100 lines of code, takes a long time to run, which in a vacuum is fine -- I have the time to wait. I've tested out the query on a small dummy dataset so I know it works. But when I ran it on the "real" data, it ran for two hours *exactly* and then spat out this error:

```
[Date] completed in 2 h 0 m 0 s 15 ms
[Date] Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is:
[Date]  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Now, I've looked on SO and in Google for mentions of this error message, and I've found them. But in every case I've seen, users were encountering this in Postgres servers out there on the web (e.g. Amazon Redshift) and not on their local machines, like mine ([this is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696745/timeouts-connecting-to-a-postgres-database-on-amazon-rds-from-azure)).

This is perhaps a bit vague. I'm happy to post an anonymized version of the query for inspection (lord knows it could probably be optimized to run faster), but again, I'm pretty sure the query itself isn't the issue here. (I grant that I may be wrong about this.)

**What I'm thinking**

My sense from reading other similar posts is that this has to do with some kind of timeout on my server side, but I'm not sure why that would happen if a query is still running (i.e. if the server is still being asked to do stuff).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you looked here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/is-it-possible-to-limit-timeout-on-postgres-server ? It's possible that you server has non-default value  for [statement_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT). But you can always turn it of with `SET statement_timeout = 0`

Comment: "it could probably be optimized to run faster" - most probably it should be possible to optimize your query and/or spilt in portions - so post details. Another: try to use psql for running heavy queries. I remember strange case with IntelliJ IDEs when defaut settings switched off query parallelism.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks. I'll set that to 0 and see what happens. Maybe go get some lunch while you wait for an update from me hehe. EDIT: didn't see your 2nd comment. By psql you just mean run the query inside PGAdmin, for example?

Comment: This looks like a network problem.

Comment: [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html) is a command-line tool for postgresql. If you have suspicions in client: first - try with psql

Comment: That is a pretty uninformative error message.  Look in the server's log file to see if it has more info.

Comment: @AlexYu -- `SET statement_timeout = 0` worked perfectly. Do you want to post that as an answer and I'll check it as correct? Sorry it took a few days to come back to this post.

Comment: @logjammin Take a look, I extended my answer a bit. Maybe you can solve your problem with  `DataGrip` settings too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After clarification from OP it became clear that DataGrip sets `statement_timeout` to value that is not enough to complete queries.

### Solution

Manually turn off statement timeout on top of your script:

```sql
SET statement_timeout = 0
```

### Notes

I don't `DataGrip` at hand but I suppose that this session parameter should be configurable for database connections.

Check documentation/forums.

Maybe that will work: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010315600-Setting-a-session-variable-for-a-Postgres-connection-